# Bundle multiple independent but related python tools in one big app

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pypy, python-packaging, software-packaging

I having been looking to find ways to achieve this but couldn't find one.

I have multiple python scripts some of them are preprocessing utility tools, some performs data analysis and some of creates visualizations. They are all related but may or may not be dependent and may have individual input arguments. I am trying to create a suite of tools in one package and want the user to choose and run the tool/module as they want.

Eg:
Here is a java based software called GATK. "gatk" is a .jar which contains several tools, one of them is "AnnotateIntervals" and it has its set of input requirements. User runs it like this

`gatk AnnotateIntervals \
          -R reference.fa \
          -L intervals.interval_list \
          --interval-merging-rule OVERLAPPING_ONLY \
          -O annotated_intervals.tsv`

https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360040098252-AnnotateIntervals

I want to develop something exactly like this in python,

`main_app.py first_module -l <> -m <>` is this even possible? if so how can I achieve this?

Comment: You want to create an app or a library? Not really understanding what gatk does

Comment: It is going be a suite of apps. One app with multiple apps with flexibility for users to choose and run individual modules with respective inputs. @drum

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read on [*setuptools*' *entry-points*](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) and/or on [*argparse*'s *sub-commands*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands). This is just one combination, probably the most "*standard*" one, but there are many other alternatives ([*poetry*](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts), [*flit*](https://flit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyproject_toml.html#entry-points-sections), [*click*](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/commands/), [*fire*](https://github.com/google/python-fire/blob/master/docs/guide.md#exposing-multiple-commands), and more).

Comment: Thanks, could you provide other alternatives? @sinoroc